# Trying to understand NSLog for printing to the console in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I'm trying to understand `NSLog` and how to print to the console in Xcode. I understand that `NSLog` uses what are called "tokens" to setup the type of variable being referenced to print (I think that's right?). What I need to know is the difference in which tokens to use and what they mean?

For example, after declaring an `NSArray` like below, I'd want to print the drink names to the console. I could do that like:

```
NSArray *drinks = @[@"juice", @"water", @"coffee"];

for (NSString *drinkName in drinks) {
    NSLog(@"%@", drinkName);
}
```

So...am I using the `@"%@"` token because it's an `NSString`?

I would use `@"%i"` for an integer, and a `@"%f"` for a float? What about doubles? If anyone could shed some easy-to-understand beginner's knowledge on NSLog, that would be great! =)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html + https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Comment: Larme's second link is what you get if you pull up `NSLog` in Xcode's documentation and follow a few of those links. Note, you generally do `%d` for integers.

Comment: Its nothing different from printf in C language. You can use formats as in C language. %lf is for double

Comment: @Satyam `%lf` is for long double. `%f` can be used for both double and float.

Comment: @rmaddy To be more precise: %f is used for double and all floats in an open arg list are automatically converted to doubles.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, NSLog isn't an Objective C function but a C function built into the foundation of Cocoa. Therefore it conforms to basic C functions with variadic arguments. You can use %@ for all objects including NSString. This will in turn call the objects description method and print the appropriate string. Most objects have a rather useful representation already there (e.g. NSArray objects return the descriptions of all their contents)